# How to use CanDeactiveGuard in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use `CanDeactivateGuard` in my angular application so that user cannot change the route until and unless he submits the form successfully. But i'm not able to achieve that.

Below is the code which I have tried

```
  export class SubmitGuard implements CanDeactivate<FillFormComponent> {

  public submittedOnce = false;

      canDeactivate(component: FillFormComponent,
                    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
                    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if(component.submitted) { // how to check if my form is submitted
          this.submittedOnce = true;
        }
        return this.submittedOnce;
      }
    }
```

Route

```
 {
            path: 'add-company-registration',
            canDeactivate: [SubmitGuard],
            // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
            loadChildren: () => import('./components/sidenav/pages/company-profile/add-company-registration/add-company-registration.module')
              .then(m => m.AddCompanyRegistrationModule)
          },
```

**Required output:** User should not change routes without submitting form. If he changes the URL without submitting the form it should redirect to the same page or shouldn't redirect to other page

Comment: Also please include the route in your question, where you use the deactivate guard

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Updated my question.

Comment: You should move `public submittedOnce = false` into the function, otherwise it will stay `true` after it's been checked once. Apart from that I dont see any problem with your code, please consider making a reproducible example showing the issue, for example on stackblitz.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the class name of the canDeactivate guard same in both the places? It seems you name it CanDeactivateGuard but use the name SubmitGuard.

Comment: @AshishDwivedi yeah it's same. My bad

Comment: @MikeS. I got stuck in if condition. How can I check did i submit the form?

Comment: remove the condition and return just `component.submitted` something like this `return component.submitted;`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan The problem is submitted is not being detected. Do i need to write in constructor and call that?

Comment: It's working now. writing in constructor Works. But if i change URL it's getting changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, how I could see your guard is correct. I just changed the condition, I think it will be better for you. Please have a look at it.
But I think the problem can be connected with the route where you added the guard.
If it is possible to try. Please add the guard in the empty route of the `AddCompanyRegistrationModule` module.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
  export class SubmitGuard implements CanDeactivate<FillFormComponent> {

      canDeactivate(component: FillFormComponent,
                    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
                    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      let submitted;
      if('submitted' in component) {
         submitted = component.submitted
      } else {
         submitted = true;
      }

         return submitted;
      }
    }
```

if you can update your question and put the routes of the `AddCompanyRegistrationModule` module I can show what I mean.

Comment: `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[SubmitGuardGuard -> AddCompanyRegistrationComponent -> AddCompanyRegistrationComponent -> AddCompanyRegistrationComponent]: ` facing two errors

Comment: `Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! SubmitGuardGuard`

Comment: did you add `@Injectable({    providedIn: 'root' })` in your guard? I have updated the answer.

Comment: if you already add the guard in the child route. please remove if from the parent route.

Comment: Ah I see, please remove your constructor, I think it is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218337/discussion-between-teja-and-ashot-aleqsanyan).